# Is function like this one reentrant?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, security, reentrant-attacks

Got this in pseudo-code (Solidity like...) from audit of past work of person from our company, in short it seems to be withdrawing first and adding later. Maybe not a good idea, especially since it's using "call" judging by the 34050 gas and not transfer?

```
function withdraw(uint256 amount) payable: 
  require amount <= balanceOf[msg.sender]
  balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount
  call msg.sender with:
     value amount wei
       gas gas_remaining - 34050 wei
  if ext_call.success:
      log Withdrawal(
            address src=_wdamount,
            uint256 amt=caller)
      return 1
  require balanceOf[msg.sender] + amount >= balanceOf[msg.sender]
  balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount
  return 0
```

Comment: What exactly is your question ?

Comment: is it re-entrant? https://medium.com/coinmonks/protect-your-solidity-smart-contracts-from-reentrancy-attacks-9972c3af7c21

Comment: Without the whole code and types we can only guess. Yes, it might be reentrant if coded poorly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is function like this one reentrant?

Is it vulnerable?

You are doing

1. Checks
2. Effects (except for the event)
3. Interactions
4. Undo changes on fail

On first look, I don't think it is, but ...

You did not check for underflow here, so msg.sender can overdraw their account and succeed.

`balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;`

That is probably the beginning of trouble.

Consider (in your style):

```
function withdraw(uint256 amount) payable: 
  require amount <= balanceOf[msg.sender]
  balanceOf[msg.sender].sub(amount)  // with safeMath
  log Withdrawal(
    address src=_wdamount,
    uint256 amt=caller)
  require
     call msg.sender with:
       value amount wei
       gas gas_remaining - 34050 wei
  return 1
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Rob, but isn't the 2nd line indeed checking for this and hence preventing underflow? I mean this one "require amount <= balanceOf[msg.sender]" - Let's say a balance is 10 and user attempts 11 - it will fail since 11 is over the balance 10, thus also preventing underflow?

Comment: You are right.  I overlooked that guard.